# Flutter Grid layout with Material that has images in Ink.image gives error "A build function returned null. The..."

Tags: dart, flutter

Im creating a game board that is 4x3. The board should conist of diffrent images. At the start Im just trying to load the same image for all pieces, however I get a error message in the app it self:

> "A build function returned null. The..."
>   [image]

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("Cat Attack"),
        ),
        body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: GridView.builder(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                gridDelegate: new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 4, // 4 columns of board buttons
                    childAspectRatio: 1.0,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 9.0,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 9.0),
                itemCount: buttonsList.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, i) => new SizedBox(
                  width: 100.0,
                  height: 100.0,

                  child: Material(
                    elevation: 4.0,
                    color: Colors.green,
                    child: Ink.image(image: AssetImage('assets/animals/cat_64_blue.png')),
                  ),

                ),
              ),
            ),

            RaisedButton(
              child: new Text(
                "Reset",
                style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20.0),
              ),
              color: Colors.red,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              onPressed: resetGame,
            )
          ],
        ));
  }
```

Comment: I don't think you should use 'new' with the SizedBox. Try removing new.

Comment: @MangaldeepPannu it's not related to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

due to of  Ink.image(image: AssetImage('assets/animals/cat_64_blue.png')), it will generate the null GridView builder error,

So use  `Image.asset('assets/animals/cat_64_blue.png'),` instead of `Ink.image(image: AssetImage('assets/animals/cat_64_blue.png')),`

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("Cat Attack"),
        ),
        body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: GridView.builder(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                gridDelegate: new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 4, // 4 columns of board buttons
                    childAspectRatio: 1.0,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 9.0,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 9.0),
                itemCount: buttonsList.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, i) => new SizedBox(
                  width: 100.0,
                  height: 100.0,

                  child: Material(
                    elevation: 4.0,
                    color: Colors.green,
                    child: Image.asset('assets/animals/cat_64_blue.png'),
                  ),

                ),
              ),
            ),

            RaisedButton(
              child: new Text(
                "Reset",
                style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20.0),
              ),
              color: Colors.red,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              onPressed: resetGame,
            )
          ],
        ));
  }
```

Comment: That works, why it is related to that problem though?

Comment: @mirkancal Because you were not having anything in `child`. Look at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 solutions for this.

I. Replace your `Ink.image` with `Image.asset('...'))`

II. Provide a `child` to `Ink.image()`, you can simply return a `Container()`.

```
Ink.image(
  image: AssetImage('assets/animals/cat_64_blue.png'),
  child: Container(), // you need this
),
```